# Is manipulating CSS-data via Integer in GWT possible?

Tags: java, css, gwt, int

I am writing a software (GWT) in which different images of soccerclubs and its names should be shown. So i wrote the following method:

```
public void updateClubNameHeader(String clubName, int logoNumber) {
    clubLabelFrame.clear();     

    HTML clubLogo = new HTML();
    clubLogo.setStyleName("clublogo_img");
    clubLabelFrame.add(clubLogo);

    Label clubNameLabel = new Label(clubName);
    clubNameLabel.setStyleName("clubnameLabel"); <--- logoNumber?
    clubLabelFrame.add(clubNameLabel);
}
```

It is no problem to change the names of the club (`clubNameLabel`), but if i want to have a new logo as well, this CSS-style is used: (filenames: 1.jpg, 2.jpg, ...)

```
.clublogo_img {
    ...
    background-image: url("images/1.jpg") !important
}
```

The problem: If i want to represent every possible club, i have to write round about ~100 styles.

The question: Is it possible to pass my integer logoNumber to the CSS, so that this one style is enough the show all the chosen logos?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to set image as background, instead of using an Image widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with CSS. You can do it with GWT:

```
clubLogo.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url(\"images/" + imageNumber + ".jpg\")");
```

Comment: URL is not property enclosed.

Comment: It must be `clubLogo.getElement().getStyle().setBackgroundImage("url(\"images/" + imageNumber + ".jpg\")");`

Comment: `setStyleName` can also be used for other settings such as `background-repeat` along with above code.